# How can I copy an old branch into the current project, so that the file system is synchronized?

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, git-extensions

After several attempts of merging the project is unusable and broken. I want to return wholly to an old remote branch. But after `checkout branch`in `Git Extensions` when I try the `Maven Update` I am getting message:

```
Unable to update Maven configuration
Could not set the project description for 'cm' because the project description file (.project) is out of sync with the file system.
```

Clean Project, Refresh won't help. (no changes)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a checkout with hard reset to the remote branch, this will restore the working directory to the remote branch's state removing any new files. 
If your remote branch was in working condition then you should be able to run "maven update".